# How to restrict the type of object created by `mapValues` in lodash?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have created an object `reducerKeys` with keys and values equal to the keys of another object `reducers`. I expected the type of `reducerKeys` would be something like this `{[key in keyof typeof reducerKeys]: key}` but I found its type is `{[key in keyof typeof reducerKeys]: string}`.

Here's my code:

```
const reducers = {
  auth: authReducer,
  travel: travelReducer,
}

export const reducerKeys = _.mapValues(reducers, (_, key) => key)
```

**Update:**
I expected the type of `reducerKeys` is `{auth: "auth", travel: "travel"}` but I found it `{auth: string, travel: string}`